# Show a % based on a product price in woocommerce

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, price

I'd like to calculate a percentage(%) of the current product price in woocommerce.
The best for me would be to be able to add the code to each product, cause different products will have different percentage for toll fee.
So, If there is a function or a Javascript for this it would be awesome..

sorry, but i can't find any code for this anywhere.

I.e.

- Product price: $100
- Toll fee(2%): $2

"You must pay a toll fee of **$2** if you order this product"

Formula: 100 * 0,02

Thanks guys!

Comment: Are you asking how to multiply two numbers?

Comment: Hehe, sort of. I'm not a coder, so i need help with setting up a snippet for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple Javascript solution won't be enough to solve this problem. You need to update the cart item price before calculation the total amount payable. Otherwise your customer won't be charged at all.

I've written a simple plugin to solve this. Here is the code-

```
<?php

/*
* Plugin Name: Toll on products
* Plugin URI: http://makjoybd.com/projetcs/wordpress/plugins/toll-on-product/
* Description: Allow to have tolls on products
* Author: Mahbub Alam <makjoybd@gmail.com>
* Version: 1.0
* Author URI: http://makjyoybd.com/
*/

class Toll_On_Products{
    public function __construct(  ) {

        //  initialization
        add_action( 'admin_init', array($this, 'woocommerce_installed') );


        //  setup field in the product edit page
        add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', array($this, 'product_fields') );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', array($this, 'save_field_input') );

        //  display notification in the product page.
        add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', array($this, 'notification') );
        add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', array($this, 'notification') );
        add_action('woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', array($this, 'cart_notification'), 20, 3 );

        add_shortcode( 'product-toll-amount', array($this, 'product_toll_amount') );

        // Uncomment it if you want to charge your users    
        // add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', array($this, 'add_toll_price') );
    }

    /**
     * Check if woocommerce is already installed or not
     * If woocommerce is not installed then disable this plugin
     * and show a notice in admin screen.
     */

    public function woocommerce_installed() {
        if ( is_admin() && ( ! class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) && current_user_can( 'activate_plugins' ) ) ) {
            add_action( 'admin_notices', array($this, "admin_notification") );

            deactivate_plugins( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) );

            if ( isset( $_GET['activate'] ) ) {
                unset( $_GET['activate'] );
            }
        }
    }

    public function admin_notification(  ) {
        echo '<div class="error"><p>' . sprintf( __('Activation failed: <strong>WooCommerce</strong> must be activated to use the <strong>Toll on products</strong> plugin. %sVisit your plugins page to install and activate.', 'woocommerce' ), '<a href="' . admin_url( 'plugins.php#woocommerce' ) . '">' ) . '</a></p></div>';
    }

    /**
     * add toll amount field in the product general tab
     */

    public function product_fields(  ) {

        echo '<div class="wc_input">';

        woocommerce_wp_text_input(
            array(
                'id'          => '_woo_toll_input',
                'label'       => __( 'Toll for this product', 'woocommerce' ),
                'placeholder' => '',
                'desc_tip'    => 'true',
                'description' => __( 'Enter the amount of toll for this product here in percent.', 'woo_uom' )
            )
        );
        echo '</div>';
    }

    /**
     * save meta value for the product
     * @param $post_id
     */

    public function save_field_input( $post_id ) {
        $woo_toll_input = isset( $_POST['_woo_toll_input'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_woo_toll_input'] ) : "";
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_woo_toll_input', esc_attr( $woo_toll_input ) );
    }

    public function get_adjusted_price( $ID ) {
        $amount = get_post_meta($ID, '_woo_toll_input', true);

        if($amount == "" || floatval($amount) === 0){
            return 0;
        }

        $amount = floatval($amount);

        $product = wc_get_product($ID);

        $price = $product->get_price() * $amount / 100;

        return $price;
    }

    /**
     * display notification in the product category and single page
     */

    public function notification(){
        global $product;

        $amount = $this->get_adjusted_price($product->get_id());

        if($amount === 0){
            return;
        }

        echo sprintf( __( '<p class="toll-amount">You must pay a toll fee of <b>%s</b> if you order this product.</p>', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price($amount) );
    }

    /**
     * Notification in the cart page
     *
     * @param $total
     * @param $cart_item
     * @param $cart_item_key
     *
     * @return string
     */

    public function cart_notification( $total, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
        $toll_message = "";

        $adjusted_price = $this->get_adjusted_price( $cart_item['product_id'] );

        if($adjusted_price !== 0){
            $toll_message = sprintf("<p class='toll-fee'>Toll fee: <span class='toll-fee-amount'>%s</span></p>", wc_price($adjusted_price));
        }

        return $total . $toll_message;
    }

    /**
     * Adjust cart before calculating total cart value
     * 
     * @param $cart_object
     */

    public function add_toll_price( $cart_object ) {

        foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) {

            $adjusted_price = $this->get_adjusted_price($value['product_id']);

            if($adjusted_price !== 0){
                $price = floatval( $value['data']->get_price() );
                $value['data']->set_price($price + $adjusted_price);
            }

        }
    }
    public function product_toll_amount($atts){
        $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
            'type' => 'formatted',
            'ID' => ''
        ), $atts, 'product-toll-amount' );

        if( $atts['ID'] == ""){
            global $product;
            $ID = $product->get_id();
        }
        else{
            $ID = $attr['ID'];
        }

        $price = $this->get_adjusted_price($ID);

        return $atts['type'] !== "raw" ? wc_price($price) : $price;
    }
}

new Toll_On_Products();
```

Save this code in a file with `.php` extension and upload in your `plugins` directory and then activate the plugin. Or you can simply put this code in your `functions.php` file but I wouldn't suggest this.

You will see a new field in the product edit page: Toll for this product. Enter the amount in percent and voila. You'll see some notices in product category pages, single product pages, cart page and checkout page. And ofcourse this amount will be added with the product price.
Please comment if you face any difficulties.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. I don't wish to charge the toll fee in the shop. 
In Sweden we pay toll fee ourselves after custom clearance sets the amount.
What I'm trying to achieve is to let our customers get an approx cost for the toll fee, so they know whats coming after delivery :)

Thats why its really important that we can set different % depending on what product to sell. I.e. A baby stroller is charged 2,7 %, a Sofa is charged 9 % and so on..

Comment: I think your idea to add the toll fee directly in the product will work, if there is a way to not add the fee to the product price. Just to write the % sum.

Preferably to use a short code to place via Visual Composer in Wordpress/Woocommerce

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: well in that case you can simply comment out this line `add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', array($this, 'add_toll_price') );` or may be remove it. This function is responsible to add the fee with the product price.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. How can i print the % sum with a short code?

Comment: use this shortcode `[product-toll-amount]` along with the text you want to show the users. NOTE: this shortcode will ONLY return the price calculating based on the % amount you set in the product edit page

Comment: The shortcode won't print the % amount. Only [product-toll-amount] is visible on the page... Maybe i need to add something like "add_shortcode" in the function file?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I've updated the code in my answer. I've put up a function for the shortcode there. You need to replace the code you copied earlier with the current one.

Comment: Aha, tested now. The shortcode writes 0kr (zero swedish krona). Both in the checkout page and inside the product..

Comment: ohh my mistake. I put the wrong logic there. Now this should work. Please replace the existing code with the updated code here.

Comment: Thanks, now it works perfectly. Nice job, i'm very happy :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```js
const tollTiers = {
  2: .02,
  4: .04,
  6: .06
};

const products = [
  {name: 'Widget', toll: tollTiers[2], price: 100 },
  {name: 'Gadget', toll: tollTiers[4], price: 50 },
  {name: 'Cog', toll: tollTiers[6], price: 200 },
];

const list = document.querySelector('#products');

products.forEach((product) => {
  const price = product.price;
  const fee = price * product.toll;
  const total = price + fee;
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  const text = document.createTextNode(
    `${product.name} - $${price} + $${fee} (${product.toll * 100}%) toll = $${total}.`
  );
  li.appendChild(text);
  list.appendChild(li); 
});
```

```html
<ul id="products"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

To display your dynamic calculated toll fee on archives pages and on single product pages, try:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','price_custom_label', 15 ); // Archives pages
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','price_custom_label', 15 ); // single product pages
function price_custom_label(){
    global $product;

    $toll_fee = wc_price($product->get_price() * 2 / 100);
    $text = sprintf( __( 'You must pay a toll fee of %s if you order this product', 'woocommerce' ), $toll_fee );
    echo '<p>'. $text . '</p>';
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works.

You should need to adapt it and to style it.